Naming parameters in C# class primary constructor
With the introduction of primary constructors to C# classes, I find myself deciding what casing to adopt when naming the parameters of a primary constructor. Should it be camelCased or PascalCase?
Comparing it to the record type where I have seen that pascal case is preferred for its parameter(s).
record Item(int Id, string Name);

For a class primary constructor what is the recommended casing for naming the parameters?
Camel case:
class Car(string model, string year, string brand)

Pascal case:
class Car(string Model, string Year, string Brand)

Please include reasons for choosing one over the other.

PascalCase is only preferred for record parameters because those names become the names of generated properties, and the convention is that properties are PascalCase. The general consensus is that normal primary ctor params (which don't become property names) should be named as normal parameters, see e.g. https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/7565

In records, C# generates properties for primary constructor parameters. Therefore, PascalCase is appropriate.
In non-record classes, primary constructor parameters are just parameters when used only in initializers or they may be translated into fields if used in method bodies. Therefore, camelCase is appropriate.

Example:
record R(int P);

Is translated into (by omitting all the other things that a record contains):
class R
{
    private readonly int <P>k__BackingField;

    public int P
    {
        get
        {
            return <P>k__BackingField;
        }
        init
        {
            <P>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }

    public R(int P)
    {
        <P>k__BackingField = P;
    }
}


class C(int x, int y)
{
    public int X { get; } = x;

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(y);
    }
}

Is translated into:
internal class C
{
    private int <y>P;

    private readonly int <X>k__BackingField;

    public int X
    {
        get
        {
            return <X>k__BackingField;
        }
    }

    public C(int x, int y)
    {
        <y>P = y;
        <X>k__BackingField = x;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(<y>P);
    }
}

Note that names like <X>k__BackingField are invalid C# identifiers. This avoids conflicts with user declared identifiers and makes it impossible for you to access them (except with Reflection).
I omitted some details. You can see all the details here Primary constructor demo, SharpLab.io. The C# compiler generates IL (Intermediate Language) where these identifiers are valid. What you see in the right panel of SharpLab is a back-translation to C#. My code snippets above are excerpts from it.

"When writing positional records, use pascal casing for parameters as they're the public properties of the record."
public record PhysicalAddress(
    string Street,
    string City,
    string StateOrProvince,
    string ZipCode);

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/identifier-names
